# Add Developed App As App Part or Webpart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have an Office 365 SharePoint Online E3, I developed my own app using visual studio 'Cloud Business App'
After I have added it to SharePoint Online Catalog as App_Name.App, now I want to add it as an 'App Part' Or WebPart I tried Deployment to specific SharePoint site (My public site), but it did not work. did I manipulate this right from the start. Did I just used the wrong category (Cloud Business App)?
Please I need your experience with this.

Thank you so much

Edit: Guys I finally can add it to the site, but the thing is I have to Add Client Wep Part first, to do that I have to attach the Client Web Part to an existing Page, now I attached it to myPage.htm in HTMLClient  '~remoteAppUrl/HTMLClient/[YOUR-PAGE].htm?{StandardTokens}' but I received this error as in the screen shot below.

[image: Error Adding Client Web Part]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an Client Web Part item?

Refer to [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179921(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179921%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you man for the replay, I should attach the ClientWebObject to an existing page. you have any idea how to attach it to an existing LightSwitch Screen?